# 3-d warping in openCV for marker detection

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a code for marker detection.from my web cam i am taking input image of marker ,this marker inside it has one reference point .I have to detect that reference point.for that i need some warping method.i know how to do the 2-d warping via **cvGetPerspectiveTransform()** and **cvWarpPerspective()** in opencv.but i want to ask that is there any way by which i can generate some 3-d perspective transform matrix that can be used in 3-d warping.

```
 cvGetPerspectiveTransform(rectangles[rectIndex].OuterCorner, dstCorners,map_matrix);
 cvWarpPerspective(workGrayImg,projectedImg,map_matrix,CV_INTER_LINEAR |CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS ,         
 cvScalarAll (0));
```

Comment: What are You trying to do? Do You try to make something based on stereovision, POSIT(pose and coordinates of a well-known object) or sth else?

Comment: My marker has **binary info** in it. with respect to the reference point the reading of that binary info will start.my camera view is 640*480.my aim is to map my marker from that 640*480 view to 240*240 pixels plane.

Comment: Is Your marker something like [this?](https://www.studentrobotics.org/images/content/marker-0.png)

Comment: my marker is like [this](http://i.imgur.com/JR49POi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small library called [ArUco](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/) that does what You are trying to do,I guess. As it is open source You can just check how they did it.

As I understand You need to find the marker first, and then make it square, so You can read the info contained inside. You can also look for methods used for QRcodes.

Comment: have you any sample code in c++ which is use to detect the marker using the ARuco library.

Comment: Take a look at `aruco_test_board.cpp` in `aruco-src/utils`